# reference to array is ambiguous error when using memset function

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-lookup, using-directives, unqualified-name

I didn't understand why i take this "strange" error. I read similar questions but it didn't answer my questions. If i define the array inside main function rather than global scope, there is no error. But assume that i have to define this array in global scope. Why do i take this error?
Here is the code  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int right[1005];
int main()
{
    memset(right,0,sizeof(right));
return 0;
}
```

Here is the error :

```
memset2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
memset2.cpp:9:9: error: reference to ‘right’ is ambiguous
  memset(right,0,sizeof(right));
     ^
memset2.cpp:6:5: note: candidates are: int right [1005]
 int right[1005];
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
             from memset2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:924:3: note:                 std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)
   right(ios_base& __base)
   ^
memset2.cpp:9:24: error: reference to ‘right’ is ambiguous
  memset(right,0,sizeof(right));
                    ^
memset2.cpp:6:5: note: candidates are: int right [1005]
 int right[1005];
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
             from memset2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:924:3: note:                 std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)
   right(ios_base& __base)
   ^
```

Comment: I am used to write all using namespace in my codes. I am really surprised now. Why you advised me to not use it? Can you guide me?

Comment: no problem in using it, but you must be sure that you never use user defined function, object or variable which has same name of C++ standard library. I think `using namespace std ` is an old style.

Comment: for example;  you can say `#include <iostream>`   then use the cout standard object like this `std::cout << "somthing" `

Comment: In what other things should i need to add "std::"? Since i always write "using namespace std;" , i don't know

Comment: one more thing is helpful.  In case of header files it is a bad practice to use `using namespace std`

Comment: before any  standard functions, objects or variables.

Comment: for initial learning having a `using namespace std` is fine. Just be aware that in general you do not want to do that as it obfuscates what you are really doing and it can even cause some problems when you accidentally use the same name as something that already exists in std:: - like is the source of your problem this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Namespace `std` has already name `right` and you included names form `std` in the global namespace by means of directive

```
using namespace std;
```

So to avoid the ambiguity use a qualified name

```
memset( ::right, 0, sizeof( ::right ) );
```

Or remove the directive and in this case you may use unqualified name `right` because the compiler will seek the name only in the global namespace.

Comment: *or **remove** the directive* :)

Comment: Link: [std::right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) - the thing that causes the naming-conflict here.

Answer (score 1):

remove `using namespace std ;` from your code and precede any standard function or object with `std::`

Answer (score -1):

If following statement has ambiguous error

```
 memset ( (char*)&mybuf, 0, sizeof(mybuf) );
```

give this a go by preceeding memset

```
std::memset ( (char*)&mybuf, 0, sizeof(mybuf) );
```